# Using application roles with DataReader

Tags: sql-server, subsonic, sqldatareader

I have an application that should use an application role from the database.
I'm trying to make this work with queries that are actually run using Subsonic (2).
To do this, I created my own DataProvider, which inherits from Subsonic's SqlDataProvider.
It overrides the CreateConnection function, and calls sp_appsetrole to set the application role after the connection is created.
This part works fine, and I'm able to get data using the application role.

The problem comes when I try to unset the application role. I couldn't find any place in the code where my provider is called after the query is done, so I tried to add my own, by changing SubSonic code. The problem is that Subsonic uses a data reader. It loads data from the data reader, and then closes it.

1. If I unset the application role *before* the data reader is closed, I get an error saying: *There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.*
2. If I unset the application role *after* the data reader is closed, I get an error saying *ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.*

I can't seem to find a way to close the data reader without closing the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to use the role for every query?

If not you can use a SharedDbConnectionScope()

```
using(var scope = new SharedDbConnectionScope())
{

    // within this using block you have a single connection
    // that isn't closed until scope.Dispose() is called
    // (happens automatically while leaving this block)
    // and you have access to scope.CurrentConnection

    // Do your init stuff
    SetRole(scope.CurrentConnection);

    var product = new Product();
    product.Code = "12345";
    product.Save();

    // Revert to normal
    UnsetRole(scope.CurrentConnection);

}
```

Comment: I did something similar.
I created a class that inherits SharedDbConnectionScope. I set the role in its constructor, and unset it on disposal.

It is indeed a good solution when you have a small number of queries. However, I needed to do this on a large number of queries.
I ended up not using application roles.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Subsonic executes its reader with CloseConnection.
If I make it not close the connection I can unset the application role after the reader is closed.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can subscribe to the event like this:

```
Connection.StateChange += new System.Data.StateChangeEventHandler(Connection_StateChange);
```

And then do some actions according to the new state of this connection:

```
if(e.CurrentState== System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
dbworker.ExecuteCommand("EXEC sp_setapprole application, 'password'");
```